# How to find surrounding or nearby areas in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Suppose I have a Google maps co-ordinate in one sublocality, is it possible to find surrounding sublocalities in, say a 5 mile radius?

My guess is we can probably zoom into that co-ord at a high zoom level, like 13 or 14,but can we capture the labels on the map around our co-ord? That would be fine for my purposes.

Has anyone attempted this, or is there a demo lying around somewhere?

Comment: Could you be a little more clear with what you're trying to achieve? I can think of a way to search the surrounding localities, and bias a search to your current locality, but I'm not sure what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google places webservice is the thing you are looking for.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Comment: Perfect! :) From their docs: "radius (required) — The distance (in meters) within which to return Place results."

Comment: Btw, if you are able to use the webservice please do mention here, I am trying to get the client id sent by google from long time.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this before, but this api should be what you are looking for: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/